# Derivation of Calculation in Modular Arithmetic Theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[image]

I'm confused on their calculation and how they arrived at their calculation that on the second line of the image below:

[image]

Comment: You recently asked a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2346467/prove-that-modular-exponentiation-is-not-well-defined) and then deleted it after it was answered. Please do not do this; it is disrespectful to the people spending their time trying to help you.

Comment: From p.307 of [Reading, Writing, and Proving: A Closer Look at Mathematics,](https://books.google.com/books?id=4QKcaXrVZb0C&pg=PA307&lpg=PA307&dq=the+proof+of+this+lemma+%22requires+the+multiplication+defined%22&source=bl&ots=1j0qe5yCz9&sig=sl-PYoP5hBk0ezqQw2vGQqeVpr0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiemZyIqPDUAhXHyj4KHYMqBL4Q6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=the%20proof%20of%20this%20lemma%20%22requires%20the%20multiplication%20defined%22&f=false) By Ulrich Daepp, Pamela Gorkin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key fact is that
$$
[xy]_n = [x]_n [y]_n
$$
Therefore,
$$
[b]_n
= [b1]_n
= [b]_n [1]_n
= [b]_n [cd]_n
= [bcd]_n
= [b]_n [c]_n [d]_n
= [b]_n [a]_n [d]_n
= \cdots
$$